# Async login with mongodb, node.js and passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

So, I got everything to work, up until the routing doesn't seem to be getting the data I'm sending into the user. But, if console.log inside of passport, it spits out the correct information. So here is my passport code, which works for the most part:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const db = require('mongodb');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('./config');

module.exports = async (passport) => {

  // =========================================================================
  // passport session setup ==================================================
  // =========================================================================

  // used to serialize the user for the session
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done) => {
    let userData = await userDb().findOne({ '_id': id});
    done(null, userData);
  });

  // Local Strategy login
  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passReqToCallback: true,
  }, async (req, username, password, done) => {
    console.log('Pulled up: ' + username);
    let userDb = await usersDb();
    let userData = await userDb.findOne({ 'email': username})

    // Check if user exists
    if (userData === null) {
      console.log('User doesn\'t exist');
      return Promise.reject('Email or password incorrect.');
    } else {
      // if user exists check password
      let passCheck = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, userData.password);
      if (passCheck) {
        console.log('Password Correct');
        return done(null, userData);
      } else {
        // if password is wrong
        console.log('Password incorrect');
        return Promise.reject('Email or password incorrect.');
      }
    }
  }));

  // DB collection
  async function usersDb() {
    const client = await db.MongoClient.connect(
    config.database,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true
      }
    );
      return client.db('kog').collection('users');
    }
};
```

heres the login route:

```
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/game',
    failureRedirect: '/',
  }), (req, res) => {
});
```

But my issues lies here:

```
// Get game route
app.get('/game', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
        res.render('game');
      } else {
        console.log('Forced redirect');
        res.redirect('/');
      }
});
```

Thought of another block that may be of an issue:

```
app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user = await req.user || null;
    next();
});
```

No matter what I do I seem to not be able to get the routing check to pull up the user data. I am not sure where I am going wrong here, as it works all up to that point. I will successfully "login" but will result in be being forcefully redirected to '/' even if everything as worked correctly.

I am fairly certain it is the fact I probably am not handling the async/await stuff correctly, but I'm not sure where I am having problems.

Comment: Still looking for an answer. Will provide files if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing :

```
passport.authenticate('local')
```

Which triggers your `passport.js` file `localStrategy`. Not sure how you got the passport file running to check to do the console.

For more, refer: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

Comment: Nope, does the exact same thing using `'local-login'` does. Updated OP with my login route.

Comment: Then almost everything looks fine. Is it redirecting to `/` after entering in `/game` or directly from passport's `failureRedirect`?

Comment: It's after the /game success redirect. I know this because of the `console.log` inside the `app.get('/game'....`.

Comment: Have you tried consoling the value of `req.user` inside `/game`?

Comment: Yup, it returns undefined. I know the user is getting populated inside my passport login strategy, because when I console `user` inside the serialize in passport it produces the correct results.

Comment: Agreed with you, this seems an issue with `async/await` and callback.